# Using Azure tags within Ansible for playbooks

Tags: azure, ansible

This is quite a broad question, as I'm unable to find any specific documentation or examples of people using what I'm going to ask, so please forgive me.

I have created an Azure ARM template and successfully able to deploy it via Ansible using the azure_rm.py dynamic inventory: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/azure_rm.py

I have read on the Ansible docs site that I am able to use AZURE_TAGS= to, what I can assume, utilise the Azure tags created when deploying a machine so I can use playbooks to only affect those tagged machines I define.

Azure docs: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/guide_azure.html

The idea is to run playbooks on certain tagged machines to update/modify their settings. Much like running against groups defined within the static Ansible hosts file.

Perhaps I have this all wrong and this is not what I can do, or perhaps it is, but for the life of me I can't find any examples of anyone using azure_tags= in  a playbook. I have no idea even if it is define within the playbook, or it's an argument.

Using this as a guide, step 12: http://codeheaven.io/15-things-you-should-know-about-ansible/

I can see how this person has utilised the tag option in the hosts parameter, and I've done this, but the machine has not been found when checking against the dynamic inventory.

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction, or better yet, give me an example of how these tag system works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone that cares, or was stuck like I was, here is the answer.

Rather than run playbooks, the following examples run the Ansible ping command against the hosts that match a given selection of hosts.

Select all VMs in Azure subscription:

```
ansible azure -i ./azure_rm.py -m win_ping
```

Select all VMs in a given region / location name (we have hosts in ukwest and uksouth - taken from the resource groups created earlier):

```
ansible ukwest -i ./azure_rm.py -m win_ping
```

Select all VMs with the tag called ServerRole set to the value WebServer

```
ansible ServerRole_WebServer -i ./azure_rm.py -m win_ping
```

When deploying VMs I've used certain tags to identify them, here is an example of using a playbook against the 'displayName' tag of 'AnsibleVM1'

```
# Run post build scripts on machines taggedd with AnsibleVM1 from commad line variable with "{{ hosts }}"
# ansible-playbook scripts.yml -i azure_rm.py --extra-vars "hosts=displayName_AnsibleVM1" --ask-vault-pass

- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  gather_facts: no

  vars_files:
   - ./vars/vault.yml
   - ./vars/vars.yml

  tasks:
   - include_vars: vault.yml
   - name: formatDataDisk script
     script: ./files/formatDataDisk.ps1

   - name: prepMachine script
     script: ./files/prepMachine.ps1

   - name: Reboot machine to apply scripts
     win_reboot:
```

And here is the command line I used to run it. note the variable is included in the command line so I can change the name on the fly:

```
ansible-playbook scripts.yml -i azure_rm.py --extra-vars "hosts=displayName_AnsibleVM1" --ask-vault-pass
```

Comment: Very good, in my case I was using tags that where identified as  `displayName_Broker`